# Check if a formula is a term in Z3Py

Tags: python, z3

In Z3Py, I need to check if something  is a term using the standard grammar `term := const | var | f(t1,...,tn)`).  I have written the following function to determine that but my method to check if for n-ary function doesn't seem very optimal.

Is there a better way to do so? These utility functions `is_term`, `is_atom`, `is_literal`, etc would be useful to be included in Z3. I will put them in the contrib section

```
CONNECTIVE_OPS = [Z3_OP_NOT,Z3_OP_AND,Z3_OP_OR,Z3_OP_IMPLIES,Z3_OP_IFF,Z3_OP_ITE]
REL_OPS = [Z3_OP_EQ,Z3_OP_LE,Z3_OP_LT,Z3_OP_GE,Z3_OP_GT]

def is_term(a):
    """
    term := const | var | f(t1,...,tn)
    """
    if is_const(a):
        return True
    else:
        r = (is_app(a) and \
                 a.decl().kind() not in CONNECTIVE_OPS + REL_OPS and \
                 all(is_term(c) for c in a.children()))
        return r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is reasonable, a few comments:

1. It depends on what you mean by "var" in your specification. Z3 has variables as de-Brujin indices. There is a function in z3py "is_var(a)" to check if "a" is a variable index.
2. There is another Boolean connective Z3_OP_XOR.
3. There are additional relational operations, such as operations that compare bit-vectors. 
   It depends on your intent and usage of the code, but you could alternatively check if the 
   sort of the expression is Boolean, and if it is ensure that the head function symbol is
   uninterpreted.
4. is_const(a) is defined as return is_app(a) and a.num_args() == 0. So is_const is really handled by the default case.
5. Expressions that Z3 creates as a result of simplification, parsing or other transformations may have many shared sub-expressions. So a straight-forward recursive descent can take exponential time in the DAG size of the expression. You can deal with this by maintaining a hash table of visited nodes. From Python you can use Z3_get_ast_id to retrieve a unique number for the expression and maintain this in a set. The identifiers are unique as long as terms are not garbage collected, so
   you should just maintain such a set as a local variable.

So, something along the lines of:

```
 def get_expr_id(e):
     return Z3_get_ast_id(e.ctx.ref(), e.ast)

 def is_term_aux(a, seen):
    if get_expr_id(a) in seen:
        return True
    else:
        seen[get_expr_id(a)] = True
        r = (is_app(a) and \
             a.decl().kind() not in CONNECTIVE_OPS + REL_OPS and \
             all(is_term_aux(c, seen) for c in a.children()))
        return r

 def is_term(a):
     return is_term_aux(a, {})
```

Answer (score 1):

The "text book" definitions of term, atom and literal used in first-order logic cannot be directly applied to Z3 expressions. In Z3, we allow expressions such as `f(And(a, b)) > 0` and `f(ForAll([x], g(x) == 0))`, where `f` is a function from Boolean to Integer. This extensions do not increase the expressivity, but they are very convenient when writing problems. The SMT 2.0 standard also allows "term" `if-then-else` expressions. This is another feature that allows us to nest "formulas" inside "terms". Example: `g(If(And(a, b), 1, 0))`.

When implementing procedures that manipulate Z3 expressions, we sometimes need to distinguish between Boolean and non-Boolean expressions. In this case, a "term" is just an expression that does not have Boolean sort.

```
def is_term(a):
   return not is_bool(a)
```

In other instances, we want to process the Boolean connectives (`And`, `Or`, ...) in a special way. For example, we are defining a CNF translator. In this case, we define an "atom" as any Boolean expression that is not a quantifier, is a (free) variable or an application that is not one of the Boolean connectives.

```
def is_atom(a):
   return is_bool(a) and (is_var(a) or (is_app(a) and a.decl().kind() not in CONNECTIVE_OPS))
```

After we define a atom, a literal can be defined as:

```
def is_literal(a):
   return is_atom(a) or (is_not(a) and is_atom(a.arg(0)))
```

Here is an example that demonstrates these functions (also available online at [rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/NCQ0)):

```
x = Int('x')
p, q = Bools('p q')   
f = Function('f', IntSort(), BoolSort())   
g = Function('g', IntSort(), IntSort())
print is_literal(Not(x > 0))    
print is_literal(f(x))
print is_atom(Not(x > 0))
print is_atom(f(x))
print is_atom(x)
print is_term(f(x))
print is_term(g(x))
print is_term(x)
print is_term(Var(1, IntSort()))
```